# Why do soldering guns use copper as a heating element?

Tags: soldering, resistance, heat, tools, conductors

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering_gun);

> The body of the tool contains a transformer with a primary winding connected to mains electricity when the trigger is pressed, and a single-turn secondary winding of thick copper with very low resistance. A soldering tip, made of a loop of thinner copper wire, is secured to the end of the transformer secondary by screws, completing the secondary circuit.
>   ... Since the tip has a much higher resistance than the rest of the tubular copper winding, the tip gets very hot while the remainder of the secondary warms much less.

So basically, it uses copper as a heating element.  The only reason the "heating element" part has a higher resistance than the rest of the copper wire is because it's thinner.

[image]

So I guess they must be made like either of the bottom two in this picture.  I figure that they must be iron plated like *soldering iron* tips, as I don't see why they would be any different.

But this must be quite inefficient, especially considering how easily it can be improved.  There must be quite a significant amount of heat generated in the wrong places, given that the "heating element" is the same material as the "conductor".  The transformers appear quite small for what's surely a very high current, which would make this more of a problem.

Another thing I see (for some tips, in the style pictured) is that the shape of the tip is too wide to have much relative resistance (if it's made of the same material), so it must rely on heat conducted from the thin wires attached to it.

So wouldn't it be better if the tip had a bit of solid iron in the current path (like the top one in the image)?  If that's too hard to manufacture, than how-about brass?  Even cheaper, why not make the entire tip piece out of brass?  These would surely all be more efficient, with the heat concentrated in the right place, and be easier on the transformer (which means a smaller, lighter transformer can be used).

Comment: You can use silver ones if you need more efficiency directly from that.

Comment: Two years on: My recollection is that the tip is made by fold and crimp and is designed to work harden and provide a much higher resistance at that point. I may be wrong :-). | If not so there would be a substantial proportion of heat ALL along the element. Heating is via I^2R so inversely proportional to area. While there is a necking down (probably in 2 dimensions) near the tip there is still a lot of area elsewhere and you'd expect the balance of the assembly to take a largish %1age of the energy. I don't think it does. It may be that tip end heats and thin feeds minimise heat conduction.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference between a soldering gun and a "regular" soldering iron is the former is only heated for a few seconds, while the latter usually stays on all the time during work.

Because of that, the gun already is more efficient than a "regular" soldering iron. Very few needs to further improve it.

Apart, from that, why not choose brass? Because brass is more rigid and likely to break. That's bad for a tool which is meant to be thrown into a tool bag.

Comment: Thank you.  But you still didn't say why _Iron_ can't be used as a heating element, only mentioning brass.  By "rigid" did you mean "brittle"?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. Brass becomes brittle when it was heated a number of times. Iron has the big disadvantage of a high µr, which results in a dramatic skin effect even at 50 Hz. The skin depth is 300µm only.

Answer (score 0):

The heating element is entirely within a centimeter or two of the
tip, and has no contact with any parts that must remain cold.  That
means the heated mass is very little more than the mass of the tip
(and the workpiece).   So, it IS efficient.   Low voltage high
current is no strain on the transformer, but does require good contact
force at the joints to the tip.

At soldering temperatures, brass is soft and brittle.   It would be
a bad material for this task (maybe titanium would do, though).

Mainly, the cold conductor that delivers current, is the thick
metal of the rod you see coming out of the transformer: that
last little bit of copper from the rod to the tip is thick enough
to not dominate the heating, and thin enough to keep the rod
from getting overheated at the joint.   The 'rod' part of
such irons is not always copper, it can be aluminum formed
in a loop as the secondary winding of the transformer.

Melting points
of interest: solder, 230C; aluminum, 660C; brass 930C; copper 1084C;
iron, 1500C; titanium 1670C.

Comment: When I was talking about efficiency, I was talking about heat _generated_ in other parts of the circuit (such as the wire around the transformer), not the heat that's conducted away from the tip. Like Janka, you mentioned that brass is too weak to be used, but you didn't mention Iron.  But if brass _were_ used, would the iron plating reinforce it?

Comment: Also, when you mentioned Titanium, you triggered my curiosity about something else.  I was thinking about possible alternatives to iron for the surfaces of soldering tips, as iron is far from perfect.  I wonder how titanium would work.

Comment: Iron confers (mainly) a resistance to dissolving in solder; yes, it does have some strength, but is usually just a thin electroplated layer, with possibly an overcoat of chrome or silver to control the tinned surface at the tip.   Titanium has strength at temperature, and forms a pretty yellow nitride rather than oxidizing, but I'm unsure of direct solder compatibility.